# Can we hide a UIView partially in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, autolayout

I have to partially hide a `UIView` when user scrolls over it. There is a `UIScrollView` above `UIView`. 
For example in the given image below i want to hide the area covered under the scrollable area which is in blue color. All my views background colors are clear color.

[image]

I want to hide the part as given in the below image, the marked rectangle which is in red color. So that part of text (One, Two, Three) is only visible.
[image]

Comment: You can add another `UIView` above it to hide scrollable area.

Comment: And what do you want to hide it with? Is there some other view added in scroll view that you want to make visible when user scrolls ?

Comment: What do you mean by hiding it partially? do you mean hide it while scrolling and showing it back when scrolling stops?

Comment: There is a content in the blue area, on scroll the side content (one, two, three) should fade out. The full screen is scrollable (in width)

Comment: Are you looking for a Slide-out menu effect ? A view to be added on partial width of the screen on scroll?

Comment: something similar but using scrollview, i give a solid background color instead of reduced opacity it works fine. Is there a way to have an hidden mask layer at the corner of scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

Each `UIView`, including `UIScrollView`, has a Core Animation Layer (a `CALayer`).

You access the `CALayer` with

```
view.layer
```

In turn, a `CALayer` has a mask, which you access with

```
layer.mask
```

Using the mask is the most comprehensive method of controlling visibility and opacity at runtime.

Comment: Using mask layer i don't think we could hide partially, as soon as we add mask layer to view it will be hidden. I managed by adding a UIView and updating the right zPosition.